# Importing a file to dictionary with a list as the value

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value-store

Please forgive me if this has already been asked an answered, but if it has, I can't find it!

I need to open a text file for data manipulation with `python`. I know how to open a file and import data as a list. I know how to open it as a dictionary. But I can't figure out how to make it do both.

My data looks like this and is in a text file:

```
key:value1:value2:value3:value4
```

I need it to be a dictionary with a list of associated values. Like this:

```
dict = {key: ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']}
```

How can I accomplish this? I'm pretty newish to programming, so showing the whole process will really help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What was your last attempt and what are the issues you're having? Please provide a [MCVE].  A snippet  sample of your data would also help understand if there are any deviants in your data structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can slice it on split.

```
d = {}
with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        sline = line.split(":") # [key,value1,value2,value3,value4]
        d[sline[0]] = sline[1:]
```

There may be more efficient ways to do it, but if your data isn't huge I don't see anything wrong with this approach.